# how to run multiple synchronous functions asynchronously?

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronous, vert.x

I am writing in Java on the Vertx framework, and I have an architecture question regarding blocking code.
I have a JsonObject which consists of 10 objects, like so:

{

"system":"CD0",

"system":"CD1",

"system":"CD2",

"system":"CD3",

"system":"CD4",

"system":"CD5",

"system":"CD6",

"system":"CD7",

"system":"CD8",

"system":"CD9"

}

I also have a synchronous function which gets an object from the JsonObject, and consumes a SOAP web service, while sending the object to it.
the SOAP Web service gets the content (e.g. CD0), and after a few seconds returns an Enum. 
I then want to take that enum value returned, and save it in some sort of data variable(like hash table).

What I ultimately want is a function that will iterate over all the JsonObject's objects, and for each one, run the blocking code,  in parallel.
I want it to run in parallel so even if one of the calls to the function needs to wait 20 seconds, it won't stuck the other calls.

how can I do such a thing in vertx?

p.s: I will appreciate if you will correct mistakes I wrote.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Heard of threads.! its seems to be does the same thing.

Comment: is that a better explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use [rxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and "zip" separate calls? Vertx has great support for rxJava  too. Assuming that you are calling 10 times same method with different `String` argument and returning another `String` you could do something like this:

```
private Single<String> callWs(String arg) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        //DO CALL WS
       return "yourResult";
    });
}
```

and then just use it with some array of arguments:

```
 String[] array = new String[10]; //get your arguments

 List<Single<String>> wsCalls = new ArrayList<>();
 for (String s : array) {
     wsCalls.add(callWs(s));
 }
 Single.zip(wsCalls, r -> r).subscribe(allYourResults -> {
     // do whatever you like with resutls
 });
```

More about zip function and reactive programming in general: [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)